# PutCassandraQL 'Cassandra Contact point' format / error in Nifi

Tags: cassandra, apache-nifi

I am using Nifi 1.1.1 and am trying to put data using a PutCassandraQL processor, but am getting

> datastax.driver.core.exceptions.Transport exception:[null] Cannot
>   connect

while trying an option : `node-0:servername.com:PORT, node-2:servername.com:PORT, node-3:servername.com:PORT`

```
edit :

    node-0.servername.com:9042,node-2.servername.com:9042,node-3.servername.com:9042
```

as given in the doumentation. Can someone tell me the cause of this error with an example of the properway to give the 'Cassandra Contact point' in Nifi

Answer (score 1):

The Cassandra Contact Points property expects a hostname or IP followed by a colon and then the port number where the Cassandra node is listening.  So if you have 3 nodes at:

```
node-0.servername.com:9042
node-2.servername.com:9042
node-3.servername.com:9042
```

Your Contact Points setting would be:

```
node-0.servername.com:9042,node-2.servername.com:9042,node-3.servername.com:9042
```

Comment: I'm sorry, @mattyb, by servername, I meant servername.com, will edit the question

Comment: Your example has a colon between node-0 and servername.com, that should be a period (if your hostname is node-0.servername.com)

Comment: tried with node-0.servername.com:9042,node-2.servername.com:9042,node-3.servername.com:9042 and still getting the same error, looks like this is a firewall issue